# Can entry points be used without installation?

Tags: python, plugins, setuptools

I've been looking into entry points, but I didn't manage to find whether they *required* installation into an environment (virtual or not) to be discoverable.

Requiring installation would be inconvenient when working on both base and extensions of a system with potentially lots of extensions. For instance Mercurial would be inconvenient if working on an extension required installing it, or if the "builtin" extensions had to be installed separately to be visible.

Comment: How do you imagine being able to use a tool or library in any way without installation?

Comment: Check out Python virtual environments for a way to install your library without making a mess all over the system.

Comment: Also perhaps learn about `python setup.py develop` and `pip install -e .`

Comment: @AlexHall yes when I am working *on* them.

Comment: @ScottColby I specifically mention virtual environments in my original post.

Comment: @Gribouillis … I know they exist, and am asking if it's possible to access entry points without these.

Comment: Entry points are from `setuptools`/`pkg_resources` so any method of accessing them without an installation will probably revolve around one of those modules. As to your other points, perhaps look at [setuptools `extras`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) for installing several things together. If this isn't your real question, perhaps edit your question to clarify what problem you are trying to solve with a concrete example of the issue or of what your "ideal" API would look like in pseudocode.